# CSS - Do Not Make Line on Top

Tags: html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwMiA.png

```
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color : gray ;
    }
.center {
    margin-top : 0px ;
    background-color : white ;
    border-left : 2px solid black ;
    margin-left : 50px ;
    margin-right : 50px ;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
    <p>a</p>
</div>
</body>
```

anyone can help to how to remove the top space , so the body can look like without space at the top . Thanks for the help

Comment: add this `*{margin:0; padding:0;}`

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes make it your answer http://jsfiddle.net/qnpmtsgx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding this `*{margin:0; padding:0;}` will remove default `margin` and `padding` which are given by browsers

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

Adding this code will do your job

Answer (score 0):

add this one to your css

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```